# Please introduce $LaTeX$ to Philosophy SE

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LateX/WebteX availability?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/latex-webtex-availability)

It would really be helpful to have it in discussions concerning formal logic. Here's the most recent example I know of where it would be helpful:

["Because if you doubt that you're doubting, you're still doubting" - What is the analogous mathematical/logical expression to this sentence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2841/1547)

Comment: Just in passing, this has actually been brought up a few times now and again. I might keep in mind enabling a TeX styling plugin is fairly expensive, and without a very compelling reason will not likely be integrated anytime soon

Comment: This has been officially declined by the team already, and I still don't see a compelling reason to enable it. As Joseph mentioned, it's a pretty heavy dependency and not something that will be used extensively enough to justify it. Using the Unicode symbols like you did in your answer seems perfectly adequate to me.

Comment: Wow, didn't know the situation was so intricate. Thank you both for taking the time to explain it to me.