# Can we please get math notation, once and for all?

Tags: feature-request

I hope I don’t need to make a persuasive case for this, but I will if requested.

Let’s get math notation like math.stackexchange has. Immediately.

(It is like drawing a picture with a cast on, trying to answer [this category theory](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104426/self-duality-in-category-theory-and-advaita-non-duality-in-metaphysics) question without mathematical notation (and ideally also native support for diagrams, although I myself do consider that asking too much, for now.))

Comment: A lot of my introductory questions about logic I was surprised to find were better answered in Philosophy SE than Math. The reason why was because mathematicians were hostile to my lack of mathematical purity, and to my verbosity and desire to speculate about the implications of this or that logical idea. Thus: logic - philosophical logic - is more at home here, than it is there. So we need logical notation.

Comment: This has been answered before. https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/latex-webtex-availability It is down to the controllers of the site, and support for LaTeX places extra load on the servers. You are right to bring your logic questions here. Philosophers invented logic and we understand it better than mathematicians! Also, we are more interested in pushing on the boundaries of the subject, so we are more tolerant of nonstandard and nonconforming questions.

Comment: God bless you sir, you are a lifesaver. So glad we have your genius mind with us on this site.

Comment: Flattery will get you everywhere.